# How to specify different buckets of Amazon s3 for different actions by active storage in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, rubygems, rails-activestorage

I have set the active storage configuration to use AWS S3 in `production.rb`, It's working fine for one bucket, but now the requirement is I wanted to use a different bucket for a specific upload. In other words I want to change the default configuration in middle of a specific uploader action.

Is it possible to achieve it?

Comment: It seems that isn't possible with ActiveStorage directly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49160670/using-multiple-buckets-with-activestorage You might want to use a AWS S3 Gem for such a specific upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an ENV or credentials for your different buckets and use it dynamically based on actions